# How to load StackExchange.Redis.dll into powershell?

Tags: powershell, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to create a powershell script to clear a redis cache, it's in Azure but I don't think that's relevant. I've seen 2 examples which I'm trying to copy where people have loaded StackExchange.Redis.dll into their script: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Saritasa.Redis/1.2.0/Content/Saritasa.Redis.psm1 and [Clearing Azure Redis Cache using PowerShell during deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978130/clearing-azure-redis-cache-using-powershell-during-deployment).

I've downloaded the current StackExchange.Redis.dll from nuget.org. I've tried to load it on 2 servers, one with .Net 4.61 installed, the other with .Net 4.8. I get the same problem on both.

If I try to use `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom` I get as below:

```
PS E:\redis\stackexchange.redis.2.2.88\lib\net461> dir


    Directory: E:\redis\stackexchange.redis.2.2.88\lib\net461


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        05/11/2021     00:42     637440 StackExchange.Redis.dll
-a---        05/11/2021     00:42     705989 StackExchange.Redis.xml


PS E:\redis\stackexchange.redis.2.2.88\lib\net461> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("E:\redis\stackexchange.redis.
2.2.88\lib\net461\StackExchange.Redis.dll")

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     E:\redis\stackexchange.redis.2.2.88\lib\net461\StackExchange.Redis.dll


PS E:\redis\stackexchange.redis.2.2.88\lib\net461> [StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer]::Connect($myConnectionStr
ing)
Unable to find type [StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is
loaded.
At line:1 char:1
+ [StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer]::Connect($myConnectionString)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (StackExchange.R...tionMultiplexer:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

PS E:\redis\stackexchange.redis.2.2.88\lib\net461>
```

If I try to use `Add-Type` I get:

```
PS E:\redis\stackexchange.redis.2.2.88\lib\net461> Add-Type -AssemblyName .\StackExchange.Redis.dll
Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly '.\\StackExchange.Redis.dll' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly
name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -AssemblyName .\StackExchange.Redis.dll
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

PS E:\redis\stackexchange.redis.2.2.88\lib\net461>
```

I've looked through the dependencies in nuget.org, I saw one non-Microsoft one called Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial which I also downloaded and got the same thing. There's a whole hierarchy of other dependencies which I think are all part of .Net, surely I haven't got to download them all if .Net is installed on the server? Thanks for any help, I've been trying all day!

Comment: Try this: `Add-Type -LiteralPath 'E:\redis\stackexchange.redis.2.2.88\lib\net461\StackExchange.Redis.dll'`

Comment: Thanks @zett42 this was definitely helpful. When using -LiteralPath I get a different error message "Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information", and then I type `$error[0].Exception.GetBaseException().LoaderExceptions` (which I found googling) which shows the DLL and version which it is missing. I'm still trying things, I'll update again when I've come to some conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put some things I learned above my code in case someone as inexperienced as me reads this. These points aren't in any order:

- To download a nuget package for use by powershell, the easiest way is to use the Install-Package cmdlet, for example:
  `Install-Package -Name System.IO.Pipelines  -ProviderName NuGet  -SkipDependencies -Destination C:\Stackexchange.Redis-packages -RequiredVersion 5.0.1`
  Note that -SkipDependencies is needed because without it Install-Package gave me an error message about a circular dependency, described in https://endjin.com/blog/2020/12/how-to-consume-a-nuget-package-in-powershell. You have to download the dependencies yourself!
  The alternative is: in nuget.org click the download link to download the .nupkg file, rename it to .zip, extract the files, then in File Explorer right-click the dll file, click Properties, Unblock.
- I thought this app was great for showing the DLL dependencies of a DLL, it shows the whole heirarchy of dependencies and if they're found or not https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies
- To get the assembly versions of dll files in powershell:
  `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse | Select-Object Name,@{n='FileVersion';e={$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}},@{n='AssemblyVersion';e={[Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version}}`
  from [Get file version and assembly version of DLL files in the current directory and all sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267009/get-file-version-and-assembly-version-of-dll-files-in-the-current-directory-and)
- When loading DLLs, `Add-Type` behaves differently from `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom()`. Add-Type seems to load dependencies which can be useful. If `Add-Type -Literalpath <dllFileName>` fails with an error message “Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more
  information” you can get the DLL it was looking for with `$error[0].Exception.GetBaseException().LoaderExceptions` https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7a4vw6/addtype_how_do_i_retrieve_the_loaderexceptions/
- To get round the situation where DLLs in the heirarchy have a dependency on different versions of the same DLL (which seems to be very common) this guy's solution is simply fantastic. I couldn't find any alternative and it seems to work perfectly https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/powershell-binding-redirects-and-visual-studio-team-services/

**The DLLs I used**
I ended up with these DLL files in a folder:

```
Name                                       FileVersion   AssemblyVersion
----                                       -----------   ---------------
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll          6.0.21.52210  6.0.0.0
Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial.dll           2.2.0.45337   1.0.0.0
StackExchange.Redis.dll                    2.2.88.56325  2.0.0.0
System.Buffers.dll                         4.6.28619.01  4.0.3.0
System.IO.Pipelines.dll                    5.0.120.57516 5.0.0.1
System.Memory.dll                          4.6.28619.01  4.0.1.1
System.Numerics.Vectors.dll                4.6.26515.06  4.1.4.0
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll 6.0.21.52210  6.0.0.0
System.Threading.Channels.dll              6.0.21.52210  6.0.0.0
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll      4.6.28619.01  4.2.0.1
```

**The code** It's not finished, but shows the Stackexhange.Redis DLL loaded and used.

```
# Code to load the DLLs needed for Stackexchange.Redis.dll and clear the cache
# Basically copied from https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/powershell-binding-redirects-and-visual-studio-team-services/

$DllPath = 'C:\Stackexchange.Redis-packages\combined DLLS'
$redisHostName = '<my cache name here>.redis.cache.windows.net'
$redisConnectionString = '<my cache name here>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=<my cache password here>,ssl=True,abortConnect=False'

# Load DLL assemblies into memory, required by the event handler below
$SystemBuffersDll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$DllPath\System.Buffers.dll")
$SystemRuntimeCompilerServicesUnsafeDll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$DllPath\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll")
$SystemMemoryDll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$DllPath\System.Memory.dll")
$SystemSystemThreadingTasksExtensionsDll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$DllPath\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll")
$SystemIoPipelinesDll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$DllPath\System.IO.Pipelines.dll")
$MicrosoftBclAsyncInterfacesDll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$DllPath\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll")
$PipelinesSocketsUnofficialDll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$DllPath\Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial.dll")
$SystemThreadingChannelsDll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$DllPath\System.Threading.Channels.dll")

# Event handler to be run when the AssemblyResolve event occurs
$onAssemblyResolveEventHandler = [System.ResolveEventHandler] {
    param($sender, $e)

    Write-Verbose "Assembly resolve event for $($e.Name)"

    $dllName = $e.Name.Split(',')[0]
  
    switch ($dllName) {
        'System.Buffers' {return $SystemBuffersDll}
        'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe' {return $SystemRuntimeCompilerServicesUnsafeDll}
        'System.Memory' {return $SystemMemoryDll}
        'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions' {return $SystemSystemThreadingTasksExtensionsDll}
        'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces' {return $MicrosoftBclAsyncInterfacesDll}
        'Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial' {return $PipelinesSocketsUnofficialDll}
        'System.Threading.Channels' {return $SystemThreadingChannelsDll}
        'System.Numerics.Vectors' {return $SystemNumericsVectorsDll}
        'System.IO.Pipelines' {return $SystemIoPipelinesDll}
    }

    foreach($assembly in [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
        if ($assembly.FullName -eq $e.Name) {
        return $assembly
        }
    }
      return $null
}

# Set up the handler above to be triggered when the AssemblyResolve event occurs
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.add_AssemblyResolve($onAssemblyResolveEventHandler)


# Load StackExchange.Redis.dll, prefer Add-Type because it seems to include dependencies, LoadFrom doesn't so might get an error later
Add-Type -LiteralPath  "$DllPath\StackExchange.Redis.dll"    

$redis = [StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer]::Connect("$redisConnectionString, allowAdmin=true")
$redisServer = $redis.GetServer($redisHostName, 6380)
# $rs.FlushAllDatabases(async=true)
$redisServer.FlushAllDatabases()

# Detach the event handler (not detaching can lead to stack overflow issues when closing PS)
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.remove_AssemblyResolve($onAssemblyResolveEventHandler)
```